# LINQ query to to iterate through list of lists but select an item at the upper level matching given filter conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

```
Public Class User
{
public List<SpecificUser> SpecificUsers{get;set;}    
}

Public Class SpecificUser
{
public bool IsDefault{get;set;}
public List<SpecificUserRole> SpecificUserRoles{get;set;}
}

Public Class SpecificUserRoles
{
public bool IsPrimary{get;set;}
}
```

**Requirement**:Given an user object,I want to get only that SpecificUser object  with IsDefault=true and which(That specific user) has 'a' SpecificUserRole
with IsPrimary=true.
This is what I have tried but it is returning bool instead of an instance of SpecificUser.

```
var defaultSpecificUser = user.SpecificUsers.Select(au => au.IsDefault && au.SpecificUserRoles.Select(aur => aur.IsPrimary).FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am able to achieve it by two queries;but want to do it in one shot:

```
var defaultSpecificUsers = user.SpecificUsers.Where(au => au.IsDefault).ToList();
var primarySpecificUser = defaultSpecificUsers .FirstOrDefault(ddau => ddau.SpecificUserRoles.Select(aur => aur.IsPrimary).FirstOrDefault());
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems simple enough:

```
user.SpecificUsers.Where(su => su.IsDefault == true && su.SpecificUserRoles.Any(sr => sr.IsPrimary == true));
```

Or simplified:

```
user.SpecificUsers.Where(su => su.IsDefault && su.SpecificUserRoles.Any(sr => sr.IsPrimary);
```

This of course assumes more than one specific user meets the criteria. If you only want one, replace `Where` for `First` or `FirstOrDefault` if you don't know for sure if one exists.